# how does the value of variable get changed through swap function?

Tags: c++, pointers, swap

Here I have two swap functions

```
void kswap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int* temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}


void kswap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

The value only changed inside of the first function,

and the second function change the value permanently..

Can anyone tell me the different between two functions?
I thought as both functions take pointer type through parameter, the value would be changed through both functions..

Comment: Lookup for dereferencing pointers and what it does.

Comment: The parameters are pointers, but they do different things with them. Indeed, read up on what `int* temp = a;` means vs `int temp = *a;`

Comment: The question can help you understand pointers. [Already solved here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672805/c-swapping-pointers)

Answer (score 2):

In function swap, `a` and `b` are `int *`, aka `integer pointers`,  that means
they contain address of an integer in memory. As seen in diagram below:

```
              Memory
          ==================
          +----------------+
          |                |
 +------> |   num1 = 5     |
 |        |                |
 | +----> |   num2 = 6     |
 | |      |                |
 | |      |                |
 | |      |================|
 | |      | Function swap  |
 | |      |                |
 +-(------------ a         |
   |      |                |
   +------------ b         |
          |                |
          +----------------+
```

Here,

```
`*a`  : should be read as : `value at address contined in a`
`*b`  : should be read as : `value at address contined in b`
```

**In first example**

In first `kswap`, after executing below statements,

```
int* temp = a;  /* A pointer which points to same place as 'a' */
a = b;          /* 'a' will now point to where 'b' is pointing */

b = temp;       /* 'b' will now point to where 'temp' is pointing
                 *  that means where 'a' was previously pointing */
```

the result is:

```
               Memory
          ==================
          +----------------+
          |                |
 +------> |   num1 = 5     |  <------+
 |        |                |         |
 | +----> |   num2 = 6     |         |
 | |      |                |         |
 | |      |                |         |
 | |      |================|         |
 | |      | Function swap  |         |
 | |      |                |         |
 + +------------ a         |         |
 |        |                |         |
 +-------------- b         |         |
          |                |         |
          |    temp -----------------+
          +----------------+
```

Note that, neither `*a` or `*b` is assigned any value, so neither of:

```
`*a`  : that is : `value at address contined in a`
`*b`  : that is : `value at address contined in b`
```

are changed.

So as seen in above picture, `num1` is still `5`, and `num2` is still `6`.
Only thing that has happended is that `a` is pointing to `num2`, and `b` is
pointing to `num1`.

**In second example**

In second `kswap`,  after executing below statements,

```
int temp = *a;  /* An int variable which will contain the same value as the
                 * value at adress contained in a */

*a = *b;        /* value at address contained in 'a' will be equal to value
                 * at address contained in 'b' */

*b = temp;      /* value at address contained in 'b' will be equal to value
                 * contained in 'temp' */
```

the result is:

```
              Memory
         ==================
         +----------------+
         |                |
+------> |   num1 = 6     |
|        |                |
| +----> |   num2 = 5     |
| |      |                |
| |      |                |
| |      |================|
| |      | Function swap  |
| |      |                |
+-(------------ a         |
  |      |                |
  +------------ b         |
         |                |
         |    temp = 5    |
         +----------------+
```

Note that, both `*a` or `*b` are assigned new value, so both:

```
`*a`  : that is : `value at address contained in a`
`*b`  : that is : `value at address contained in b`
```

are changed.

And as seen in above picture, `num1` is now `6`, and `num2` is now `5`. So in the second example, values of variables `num1` and `num2` are permanently changed.

Answer (score 1):

Assume each function is called as:

```
void f()
{
    int x = 101, y = 999;    
    kswap(&x, &y);
}
```

Remember that in `C++` arguments are passed by value, so `kswap` receives the *values* of the addresses where `x, y` reside. The rest of the answer is inlined in the code comments below.

The `kswap` that works.

```
void kswap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;  // `a` is the address of `int x`
                    // `*a` is the integer value at address `a`
                    //  i.e. the value of `x` so temp == 101 now

    *a = *b;        // same as above `*b` is the value of `y` i.e. 999
                    // now this integer value is copied to the address where `a` points
                    // effectively overwriting the old `x` value `101` with `999`

    *b = temp;      // finally, this copies the value in `temp` i.e. 101
                    // to the address where `b` points and overwrites
                    // the old `y` value `999`, which completes the swap
}
```

The `kswap` which does *not* work.

```
void kswap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int* temp = a; // this copies `a` i.e. the address of `x`
                   // to local variable `temp`

    a = b;         // this copies `b` to `a`
                   // since arguments `a` and `b` are pointers and passed by value
                   // this only modifies the value of variable `a`
                   // it does **not** change `x` or its address in any way

    b = temp;      // this copies 'temp' to 'b', same comments as above
                   // now 'a' holds the address of `y` and `b` holds the address
                   // of `x` but **neither** 'x' nor 'y' values have been modified
                   // and pointer variables `a`, `b` go out of scope as soon as
                   // the function returns, so it's all a big no-op in the end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first function swaps the addresses, but not outside the scope of the function.
The second function swaps the values, and outside the function's scope.
Adding the `*` to the name, means you want the value, not where it's at.

Comment: The first function swaps *nothing* for the *caller*, which is the important part, and somewhat the point of a "swap" function.